# local machine vs travis.ci returning different results for `Date.toISOString()`

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, travis-ci

I just ran into a scenario where an assertion on `new Date(1999, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1).toISOString()` is causing a test failure when run on in my ci process (travis), but passes on my local machine.

```
let dString = new Date(1999, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1).toISOString();
expect(dString).to.be('1999-01-01T08:01:01.000Z');
```

When run on travis.ci, I get an assertion error:

> expected '1999-01-01T01:01:01.000Z' to equal '1999-01-01T08:01:01.000Z'

It seems like a timezone issue, but I'm not sure I understand why?  On my local machine creating a new date seems to use a UTC+8 offset.

However, when run on travis, it seems like it using `UTC+0`?

Datetime & Timezones alway confuse me.

**How should I be writing this test so it passes in any environment**

Comment: you might use http://www.ntpjs.org/, this will send you the timstamp according to you network time:

Comment: What is the purpose of this test?

Comment: @customcommander obviously this isn't actual test I'm running.  I've simplified as per the SO guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

If you're just curious, its part of a query builder library for a platform API client.

Comment: @DupinderSingh - once again, the current system time doesn't have anything to do with this question, and thus recommending ntpjs is off topic.  Please reserve such suggestions for questions that are related to aligning the current time with a server's time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following line to create the date in UTC and now it passes on both platform:

`new Date(Date.UTC(1999,0,1,1,1,1)).toISOString();`

Comment: Indeed.  You've discovered that `toISOString` emits a string in UTC, and thus if you pass input parameters in the `Date.UTC` function, the output will match your expectations.